# Comparing data in 2 separate DataFrames and producing a result in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and I'm trying to produce a similar result of Excel's IndexMatch function with Python & Pandas, though I'm struggling to get it working.

Basically, I have 2 separate DataFrames:

The first DataFrame ('market') has 7 columns, though I only need 3 of those columns for this exercise ('symbol', 'date', 'close'). This df has 13,948,340 rows.

The second DataFrame ('transactions') has 14 columns, though only I only need 2 of those columns ('i_symbol', 'acceptance_date'). This df has 1,428,026 rows.

My logic is: If i_symbol is equal to symbol and acceptance_date is equal to date: print symbol, date & close. This should be easy.

I have achieved it with iterrows() but because of the size of the dataset, it returns a single result every 3 minutes - which means I would have to run the script for 1,190 hours to get the final result.

Based on what I have read online, itertuples should be a faster approach, but I am currently getting an error:

*ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)*

This is the code I have written (which currently produces the above ValueError):

```
for i_symbol, acceptance_date in transactions.itertuples(index=False):
  for symbol, date in market.itertuples(index=False):
    if i_symbol == symbol and acceptance_date == date:
        print(market.symbol + market.date + market.close)
```

2 questions:

1. Is itertuples() the best/fastest approach? If so, how can I get the above working?
2. Does anyone know a better way? Would indexing work? Should I use an external db (e.g. mysql) instead?

Thanks, Matt

Comment: Using for-loops with `pandas` / `numpy` is a last-ditch approach that essentially removes all the advantages of these libraries. There may be a better approach, but I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to accomplish. Your approach here is the brute-force approach, and it's no wonder it is taking forever. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and consider supplying a small,self-contained example of an input with an expected output. On the other hand, it does sound like a use-case for a relational db.

Comment: Simply merge: `pd.merge(market[['symbol', 'date', 'close']], transactions[['i_symbol', 'acceptance_date']],  left_on=['symbol', 'date'], right_on=['i_symbol', 'acceptance_date'])`. No need for looping.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding question 1:** pandas.itertuples() yields one [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for each row. You can either unpack these like standard tuples or access the tuple elements by name:

```
for t in transactions.itertuples(index=False):
  for m in market.itertuples(index=False):
    if t.i_symbol == m.symbol and t.acceptance_date == m.date:
        print(m.symbol + m.date + m.close)
```

(I did not test this with data frames of your size but I'm pretty sure it's still painfully slow)

**Regarding question 2:** You can simply [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both data frames on symbol and date.

Rename your "transactions" DataFrame so that it also has columns named "symbol" and "date":

```
transactions = transactions[['i_symbol', 'acceptance_date']]
transactions.columns = ['symbol','date']
```

Then merge both DataFrames on symbol and date:

```
result = pd.merge(market, transactions, on=['symbol','date'])
```

The result DataFrame consists of one row for each symbol/date combination which exists in both DataFrames. The operation only takes a few seconds on my machine with DataFrames of your size.

Answer (score 0):

@Parfait provided the best answer below as a comment. Very clean, worked incredibly fast - thank you.

```
 pd.merge(market[['symbol', 'date', 'close']], transactions[['i_symbol',
 'acceptance_date']], left_on=['symbol', 'date'], right_on=['i_symbol',
 'acceptance_date']).
```

No need for looping.